# How to retain the global variebles when application is upgraded to new version in android?

Tags: android, versioning, upgrade

In my android application ,user has to register by agreeing the terms and condition giving their email id. If user upgrade the application to next version, I should not get the agreement page or email registration window. I am controlling it using global variables but if user upgrade application to newer version, global variables get reset, so user get the agreement page and registration window again. So how can I do this? Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You Have two ways to storing your data @ local media.

- `Shared Preference`
- `SQLite Database`

**When i should use Shared Preference ?**

If your number of storing variable are not more and it should be primitive values then you can use `Shared Preference` .

See [This](http://saigeethamn.blogspot.in/2009/10/shared-preferences-android-developer.html) for sample code .

**Or**

**When  i should use SQLite Database ?**

If you have to store number of variable and which are not primitive and also you need that data for long time then you should  use `SQLite Database`.

See [This](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html) for sample code .

Now its **`Depends on you as per your requirement.`**

Comment: It will be more useful if u tel more about how can shared preferences can be used effectively for this situation

Comment: Thank you Manoj for such guidance. i appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

```
class VersionInfo {

private VersionInfo() {}

private static final String PREF_VERCODE = "VERCODE";

public static final VersionInfo INSTANCE = new VersionInfo();

void setVersionCode(Context ctx, int ver) {
     PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx).edit().putInt(PREF_VERCODE, ver).commit();
    }

int getVersionInfo(Context ctx) {
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx).getInt(PREF_VERCODE, 1);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this piece of code to display the *ChangeLog* in my app to detect if the version has changed and display the *ChangeLog* accordingly. The same logic can be used for displaying or not displaying the *Agreement*, as the case may be.

These are my Global Declarations:

```
// FOR STORING VERSION CODE IN SHAREDPREFERENCES
private static final String PRIVATE_PREF = "my_app_name";
private static final String VERSION_KEY = "version_number";


try {
        // GET THE PREFERENCE SET FOR THE CHANGELOG
    final SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());

    final boolean showChanges = prefs.getBoolean("displayChangelog", false);

    PackageInfo pkgInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);

    // SET THE CURRENT VERSION IN SHAREDPREFERENCES
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = getSharedPreferences(PRIVATE_PREF, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    // SAVED VERSION CODE
    int savedVersionCode = sharedPrefs.getInt(VERSION_KEY, 0);String.valueOf(savedVersionCode));

    // GET NEW VERSION CODE
    int currentVersionCode = pkgInfo.versionCode;String.valueOf(currentVersionCode));

    Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
    editor.putInt(VERSION_KEY, currentVersionCode);
    editor.commit();

    if (showChanges == false)   {

        /*****  DISPLAY THE CHANGELOG   *****/
        // DISPLAY DIALOG WHEN THE APPLICATION IS INSTALLED FOR THE FIRST TIME
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("displayChangelog", true);
    editor.commit();

    } else if (showChanges == true && currentVersionCode > savedVersionCode)    {

        /*****  DISPLAY THE CHANGELOG AFTER AN UPGRADE  *****/
        // DISPLAY DIALOG CHANGELOG AFTER AN UPGRADE
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("displayChangelog", true);
    editor.commit();
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

EDIT: Alongwith this code, I also use a `Preferences` XML file to provide the use the ability to see the *ChangeLog* again and also store the state of the user preference to display the *ChangeLog* at next run. The XML for that:

```
<PreferenceCategory
    android:key="changeLogOptions"
    android:title="Changelog Options" >
    <Preference
        android:key="changeLog"
        android:summary="See what has changed in the current version"
        android:title="What\&apos;s New" >
    </Preference>
    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:defaultValue="false"
        android:key="displayChangelog"
        android:summary="@string/settings_changelog"
        android:title="Hide The Changelog" >
    </CheckBoxPreference>
</PreferenceCategory>
```