# Shared Preferences

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, android-preferences

I am trying to user SharedPrefs in my app, I simply want to retrieve a email address and password from a seperate settings activity. I have implemented

```
package com.overclockerz.webtest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class SettingScreen extends Activity {
    static EditText username;
    static EditText password;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.setting_screen);
    username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

    SharedPreferences settings =  
            getSharedPreferences("APP_PREFS", MODE_PRIVATE); 
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = settings.edit();
    prefEditor.putString("Username", username.getText().toString());
    prefEditor.putString("Password", username.getText().toString());
    prefEditor.commit();        

}

}
```

And I have tried to retrieve with 
package com.overclockerz.webtest;

```
import org.apache.http.util.EncodingUtils;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.webkit.CookieManager;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener,
        OnClickListener {
String query = "fldUsername=" + username + "&fldPassword=" + password + "&ut=3";
String username = prefs.getString("Username");
String password = getText(R.id.password).toString();

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this); 
        // then you use
        prefs.getBoolean("keystring", true);
        //there are also methods to put strings,float, longs, ints





        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setUserAgentString("SMUK");
        //myWebView.setInitialScale(100);
        //myWebView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
        CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);

        // webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webSettings.setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        myWebView.postUrl("http://test.schoolmilkuk.co.uk/parents-login",
                EncodingUtils.getBytes(query,"BASE64"));
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), query, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
         .show();
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.menu_spinner);
        // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner
        // layout
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                this, R.array.spinner_links,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        // Apply the adapter to the spinner
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        // Check if the key event was the Back button and if there's history
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && myWebView.canGoBack()) {
            myWebView.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        // If it wasn't the Back key or there's no web page history, bubble up
        // to the default
        // system behavior (probably exit the activity)
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {
        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        switch (arg2) {
        case 0:
            myWebView.postUrl("http://test.schoolmilkuk.co.uk/parents-login",
                    EncodingUtils.getBytes(query,"BASE64"));
            myWebView.loadUrl("http://test.schoolmilkuk.co.uk/parent-home");
            break;
        case 1:
            myWebView.postUrl("http://test.schoolmilkuk.co.uk/parents-login",
                    EncodingUtils.getBytes(query,"BASE64"));
            myWebView
                    .loadUrl("http://test.schoolmilkuk.co.uk/parent-change-pass");
            break;
        case 2:
            myWebView.postUrl("http://test.schoolmilkuk.co.uk/parents-login",
                    EncodingUtils.getBytes(query,"BASE64"));
            myWebView
                    .loadUrl("http://test.schoolmilkuk.co.uk/parent-add-child");
            break;
        case 3:
            myWebView.postUrl("http://test.schoolmilkuk.co.uk/parents-login",
                    EncodingUtils.getBytes(query,"BASE64"));
            myWebView
                    .loadUrl("http://test.schoolmilkuk.co.uk/parent-children-list");
            break;
        case 4:
            myWebView.postUrl("http://test.schoolmilkuk.co.uk/parents-login",
                    EncodingUtils.getBytes(query,"BASE64"));
            myWebView.loadUrl("http://test.schoolmilkuk.co.uk/parent-order");
            break;
        case 5:
            myWebView.clearCache(true);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cache Cleared :)",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
        default:
            myWebView.loadUrl("http://test.schoolmilkuk.co.uk/parent-home");
            break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.settings_menu:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, SettingScreen.class));
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

}
```

String username = prefs.getString("Username", "Username") doesn't make sense as it's not using the variables the user set because your supplying "username"? I am very very confused.

**After Following Blackbelt's Advice** (of which **all is very much appreciated**) I revised the code to and I am seeing a null pointer exception?

```
package com.overclockerz.webtest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class SettingScreen extends Activity {
    static EditText username;
    static EditText password;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.setting_screen);
        username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

        SharedPreferences settings =  
                getSharedPreferences("APP_PREFS", MODE_PRIVATE); 
        SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = settings.edit();
        prefEditor.putString("Username", username.getText().toString());
        prefEditor.putString("Password", username.getText().toString());
        prefEditor.commit();        

    }

}

package com.overclockerz.webtest;

import org.apache.http.util.EncodingUtils;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.webkit.CookieManager;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener,
        OnClickListener {
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
String username = prefs.getString("Username", "default");
String password = prefs.getString("Password", "default");

String query = "fldUsername=" + username + "&fldPassword=" + password + "&ut=3";
    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setUserAgentString("SMUK");
        //myWebView.setInitialScale(100);
        //myWebView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
        CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);

        // webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webSettings.setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        myWebView.postUrl("http://test.schoolmilkuk.co.uk/parents-login",
                EncodingUtils.getBytes(query,"BASE64"));
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), query, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
         .show();
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.menu_spinner);
        // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner
        // layout
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                this, R.array.spinner_links,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        // Apply the adapter to the spinner
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        // Check if the key event was the Back button and if there's history
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && myWebView.canGoBack()) {
            myWebView.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        // If it wasn't the Back key or there's no web page history, bubble up
        // to the default
        // system behavior (probably exit the activity)
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {
        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        switch (arg2) {
        case 0:
            myWebView.postUrl("http://test.schoolmilkuk.co.uk/parents-login",
                    EncodingUtils.getBytes(query,"BASE64"));
            myWebView.loadUrl("http://test.schoolmilkuk.co.uk/parent-home");
            break;
        case 1:
            myWebView.postUrl("http://test.schoolmilkuk.co.uk/parents-login",
                    EncodingUtils.getBytes(query,"BASE64"));
            myWebView
                    .loadUrl("http://test.schoolmilkuk.co.uk/parent-change-pass");
            break;
        case 2:
            myWebView.postUrl("http://test.schoolmilkuk.co.uk/parents-login",
                    EncodingUtils.getBytes(query,"BASE64"));
            myWebView
                    .loadUrl("http://test.schoolmilkuk.co.uk/parent-add-child");
            break;
        case 3:
            myWebView.postUrl("http://test.schoolmilkuk.co.uk/parents-login",
                    EncodingUtils.getBytes(query,"BASE64"));
            myWebView
                    .loadUrl("http://test.schoolmilkuk.co.uk/parent-children-list");
            break;
        case 4:
            myWebView.postUrl("http://test.schoolmilkuk.co.uk/parents-login",
                    EncodingUtils.getBytes(query,"BASE64"));
            myWebView.loadUrl("http://test.schoolmilkuk.co.uk/parent-order");
            break;
        case 5:
            myWebView.clearCache(true);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cache Cleared :)",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
        default:
            myWebView.loadUrl("http://test.schoolmilkuk.co.uk/parent-home");
            break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.settings_menu:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, SettingScreen.class));
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13263855/how-to-retain-the-global-variebles-when-application-is-upgraded-to-new-version-i/13263998#13263998

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences`

and

```
SharedPreferences settings =  
            getSharedPreferences("APP_PREFS", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

returns different thing.

the former will use a default file name (something like your pakage name), the latter will require a name. So do not get confused. The second parameter of `getString()` is  a default value. You can use it to check that some condiments are not meet, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

Reread docs for [getString](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getString%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29). It returns `defValue` only if there is no value in preferences. You can pass `null` as second argument. And if you get `null` it means there is no username yet set.
Also you should save username to preferences on some action, not in `onCreate`. E.g. create button "OK" and save username in `onClick` for this button.

Answer (score 0):

If you need multiple shared preferences then put some name in them.

```
SharedPreferences sp = getApplication().getSharedPreferences("someName", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

If you need just one then

```
SharedPrefrences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```